# what is difference between "Vielleicht kommt er noch." and "vielleicht kommt er"?

Tags: word-usage

I am a beginner in German language, and found the first sentence in an A1 vocabulary list. I tried Google Translator both with and without "noch". It gave similar translations in English. So I just wanted to know about the role of "noch" in this sentence.

Comment: Machine translation is a poor way to learn about the meaning of a word. This applies in particular to translating between English and German, because German tends to use adverbs and modal particles where English does not so the English translation often simply lacks an equivalent of a word in the German sentence.

Comment: Apparently the sentence come from [here](https://www.goethe.de/pro/relaunch/prf/en/Goethe-Zertifikat_A2_Wortliste.pdf) (page 22). Goethe word lists aren't meant to teach you vocabulary; you should find the meaning of the word as used in many different sentences, not just the few examples given in the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several possible meanings of *noch*, depending on context; most likely:

- despite it is a bit late already (equivalent to English *still*)
- in addition to somebody else, who is already there

Further meanings with examples can be found in [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/noch#1).

Without *noch*, the sentence is even more vague: maybe he comes, maybe not.